# IntelliJ inspection for verbose array initialisation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, inspection

Is there an inspection in IntelliJ which will detect when I have written

```
final String[] args = new String[]{​"a", "b"}​;
```

instead of the shorter (and equally valid)

```
final String[] args = {​​​"a", "b"}​​​;
```

I can't find one and I would like a weak warning when I use the more verbose form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is:
`Java | Code style issues | Redundant 'new' expression in constant array creation`

Comment: I wonder why this inspection isn't enabled by default.